# Url rewriting not working on digitalocean server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm unable to disable the `.php` extention using `.htaccess` on digitalocean server. Mode rewrite is already enabled in php.

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What's the operating system on the DO server?

Comment: I am using ubuntu server

Comment: Also it is working fine on my other servers

Answer (score 1):

You can use above code in `.htaccess` to hide `.php` extension

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Make sure you have enabled `AllowOverride All` for the directory of webroot or else it will prevent `.htaccess` from loading.

Also make sure there is rewrite extention installed and enabled

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

.. And at the end, restarting the apache2 service is good idea

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```